# How to Fetch a node and all related nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, path

I am looking forward to implement a discussion forum using Neo4j as database.
I want to fetch a question and all its answers and all the comments on the answers using questionId.
In my database all the nodes have label POST and they all have directed relationship "hasComment" `POST-hasComment->POST`

I have come up with following query:

```
Match path=((n:POST)-[:hasComment*]->(any)) return path;
```

This query is returning required data but i am getting a lot of repeated data on relationship between POSTS.
Is there a better way to fetch the information?

[This is how nodes and relationship between nodes look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e608o.png)

Comment: Filter your question by its unique identifier and you will get the expected results. Something like this: `MATCH path=((n:Post{id: 'uniqueId'})-[:hasComment*]->()) return path;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are exporting the data in JSON. You can not change the existing format, like in JSON, it is because a node can have multiple relationship (i.e. parent node can have multiple child node and child can have multiple parent) and current format tracks the parent and child relation info (i.e. who is the parent node of a child in a particular path).

You can filter the result in query itself by using any subquery or using some filters such as use of `WHERE` clause. or clean the JSON as required.